# Encode String to byte[] to invoke method via web3j

Tags: bytes, java

I have a method in a contract that receives a *bytes* object. Web3J generated code in Java translates it to a *byte[]* object as parameters.

I have the correct String "0x....." thet represents the correct bytes. How can I transform into the correct java bytes[] object to invoke the method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String encodedFunctionCall = contract.functionCall().encodeFunctionCall();
    
RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createTransaction(nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, contractAddress, encodedFunctionCall);
    
    
byte[] toBytes = TransactionEncoder.encode(rawTransaction));
```