# How to encode string as bytes array?

Tags: solidity, string, bytes, encoding

[A similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/109462/86303) has been asked but using web3 in java, however, I would like to encode a `string` to `bytes[]` in solidity itself.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go from `string` to `bytes[]` ? I guess what you are really looking for is `string` to `bytes` ?

Comment: @hroussille If I was developing I would use a byte[] i.e. bytes, however the signature for the 3rd party function that I'm using requires a bytes[].

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is exactly that you want to do ? (with the third party function code if possible)

Comment: @hroussille it accepts NFT metadata in that format of max length 100.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your string comes from an external source (someone outside your contract calls the function with such string as a parameter) you can cast it to bytes and then slice the bytes into an array. Something like this.

```
contract Cast {

    bytes [] public arr;

    function convertExternalString(string calldata str) external{
        bytes calldata bts =bytes(str);
        for(uint i; i<bts.length; i++){
            arr.push(bts[i:i+1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, if your string is stored on the contract you can also convert it but would have to change the visibility of the function `convertExternalString` to `public` and then call it with a `this.`. The next code works.

```
contract Cast {

    bytes [] public arr;
    string public st = "Hello";

    function convertInternalString() public {
        this.convertExternalString(st);
    }

    function convertExternalString(string calldata str) public {
        bytes calldata bts =bytes(str);
        for(uint i; i<bts.length; i++){
            arr.push(bts[i:i+1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that calldata slicing is only available for solidity 0.6.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it'll work, I'll approve on further confirmation.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: sorry, haven't yet tested with the 3rd party library, been a bit busy. Should have time by the end of the week.